# How can i install a specific version of onesignal-cordova-plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, onesignal

I want to install a specific version of onesignal-cordova plugin. I am writing this:

```
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin@2.8.3
```

However, the package.json and config.xml write this:

```
"onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.8.3"
```

and

```
<plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.8.3" />
```

How can I install it without the semantic in front? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin@2.8.3 -- --save-exact`

If it doesn't work, then configure npm to not add `^`, to do so, run `npm config set save-prefix=""`